# How do I pass a nested list to the helm_release resource?

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm, terraform-helm-provider

I need this config:

```
ingress:
  hosts:
    - host: test.example.io
      paths: [/path]
```

I attempted this and got an error:

```
  set_list {
    name  = "ingress.hosts"
    value = ["{host: *, paths [/*]}"]
  }

Error: failed parsing key "ingress.hosts" with value {host: *, paths [/*]}, key "}" has no value
```

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you would need to double escape (because Go DSL) any characters that would be interpreted/resolved by HCL2. Specifically the `[]` is a `list` type constructor, and the `{}` is a `map` type constructor.

```
set_list {
  name  = "ingress.hosts"
  value = ["\\{host: *, paths \\[/*\\]\\}"]
}
```